# C++0x Smart Pointer Comparisons: Inconsistent, what's the rationale?

Tags: c++, c++11, std, smart-pointers

In C++0x (n3126), smart pointers can be compared, both relationally and for equality. However, the way this is done seems inconsistent to me.

For example, `shared_ptr` defines `operator<` be equivalent to:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
bool operator<(const shared_ptr<T>& a, const shared_ptr<T>& b)
{
    return std::less<void*>()(a.get(), b.get());
}
```

Using `std::less` provides total ordering with respect to pointer values, unlike a vanilla relational pointer comparison, which is unspecified.

However, `unique_ptr` defines the same operator as:

```
template <typename T1, typename D1, typename T2, typename D2>
bool operator<(const unique_ptr<T1, D1>& a, const unique_ptr<T2, D2>& b)
{
    return a.get() < b.get();
}
```

It also defined the other relational operators in similar fashion.

---

Why the change in method and "completeness"? That is, why does `shared_ptr` use `std::less` while `unique_ptr` uses the built-in `operator<`? And why doesn't `shared_ptr` also provide the other relational operators, like `unique_ptr`?

I can understand the rationale behind either choice:

- with respect to method: it represents a pointer so just use the built-in pointer operators, versus it needs to be usable within an associative container so provide total ordering (like a vanilla pointer would get with the default `std::less` predicate template argument)
- with respect to completeness: it represents a pointer so provide all the same comparisons as a pointer, versus it is a class type and only needs to be less-than comparable to be used in an associative container, so only provide that requirement

But I don't see why the choice *changes* depending on the smart pointer type. What am I missing?

---

Bonus/related: `std::shared_ptr` seems to have followed from `boost::shared_ptr`, and the latter omits the other relational operators "by design" (and so `std::shared_ptr` does too). Why is this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This was a defect in drafts of C++11; a defect report was opened to change the `std::unique_ptr` relational operator overloads to use `std::less`:  see [LWG Defect 1297](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-active.html#1297).

This was fixed in time for the final C++11 specification.  C++11 §20.7.1.4[unique.ptr.special]/5 specifies that the `operator<` overload:

> *Returns:*  `less<CT>()(x.get(), y.get())`

where `x` and `y` are the two operands of the operator and `CT` is the common type of the two pointers (since pointers to different types, e.g. with different cv-qualifications, can be compared).

Comment: Ah, I should of looked there first. :) That definitely answers the change in method, but do you know why `shared_ptr` wouldn't provide all the other relational operators?

Comment: @GMan:  I think that might be a mistake.  They are listed in 20.9 in the `<memory>` synopsis, but they are not actually present in 20.9.11.2.7...

Comment: @James: Oh, good call. I was just scoped on the `shared_ptr` section. Well, that solves that I guess. (They should really clean that up.) Thanks.

Comment: @GMan:  Though, the defect may in fact be with the `<memory>` synopsis.  Boost and TR1 only specify `==`, `!=`, and `<`.  Boost says "The rest of the comparison operators are omitted by design."  I haven't found any justification for that design choice on the Boost mailing list or in any of the WG21 papers yet.

Comment: More curiously:  even though the other three relational operators are not overloaded for `shared_ptr`, the `greater`, `greater_equal`, and `less_equal` class templates are all specialized for `shared_ptr`.

Comment: @James: That's awkward. :S I'm searching through proposals trying to see why that's the case. By the way, I'm unaccepting for now so more people will check out the question and these comments. You'll get em back. :)

Comment: @GMan:  The Boost rationale seems to be something along the lines of:  Because you can't compare arbitrary pointers in C++ using the four relational operators unless those pointers point at subobjects of some array or class and because you'll never have shared_ptrs pointing to subobjects (at least not in the intended use of shared_ptr), they don't implement the relational operators for shared_ptr.  However, they want you to be able to use shared_ptr as a map key and for some reason they found it easier to overload op< than to specialize std::less (for compatibility reasons, probably).

Comment: That said, I still don't know why shared_ptr and unique_ptr differ with respect to which operators they overload.  Regardless, either 20.9 or 20.9.11.2.7 is wrong (they can't both be right).  Do you want to submit a defect or shall I?

Comment: You shall. :) I don't know how. :S

Comment: @GMan:  Nevermind!  Take a look at N3126 20.3.1.  There are general purpose operator templates in namespace `std` for `!=`, `>`, `<=`, and `>=`.  These were even present in C++03 20.2.1.  (Well, I've certainly learned something interesting today... I had no idea that those were there!)

Comment: @James: Whoa, never saw that. Everything makes much more sense now!

Comment: @JamesMcNellis, @GMan: They're in namespace `std::rel_ops`, not `std`. They are not as useful as they appear to be.

Comment: @Charles:  Oh, right; if you scroll up the page they are indeed those declared in `rel_ops`.  That said, the comparisons are still consistent between the two.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis: FWIW `shared_ptr<T>` has a constructor with the explicit purpose of creating a pointer to a subobject.  `unique_ptr<T>` can't have a pointer to a subobject (`unique_ptr<T, D>` can, if the deleter is sufficiently magic)